# Displaying CSS from database based on selector and declaration (key => value)

Tags: php, html, css

I'm storing basic CSS settings in a database so they can be configurable by a client using some sort of web form, then these can be echoed out within the `style` tag and override any existing settings. Basic settings like font family, background color, font color etc.

**Table:**

[image: CSS settings stored in table]

Rather than setting a column name for every css selector, I have decided to store settings like shown above as this would be easier to update and maintain.

I am trying to echo the "style_name" followed by "{", then every "style_value" then a closing tag "}". I'm nearly there, but I'm trying to figure out how to know when all style values associated with the style name have been echoed, then echo a closing tag, rather than after every value.

**PHP Code:**

```
$sql = 'SELECT style_name, style_value FROM style ORDER BY style_name';
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$unique_css = array();

foreach ($results as $css) {
    if (!in_array($css->style_name, $unique_css))  {
        $unique_css[] = $css->style_name;
        echo $css->style_name . " { " . $css->style_value;
    } else {
        echo $css->style_value;
    }
    echo '}';
}
```

**Returns:**

```
body {
    background: #CCC; }
    font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif; }
    font-size: 40px; }
    text-align:center;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}
```

I understand that I could just echo every style name with value e.g.:

```
body { value1 } body {value2}
```

But I think that is just messy IMO. Help appreciated!

Comment: You want body { value1 } body {value2} on the result?

Comment: Nah I don't want that. That would be the fall back option. I want `body { value1; value2; }`

Comment: You probably needs to sort your result with style_name order by style_name. Using this you will get all the style of particular style in sequence, then do some logics. All the best.

Comment: Yeah, it's already ordered by style_name if you check the SQL, but I just can't figure out how to echo "}" at the right time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the best solutions is to use proper MySQL to group by the style names by using the `GROUP_BY` keyword and concatenating the style value string with `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT style_name, GROUP_CONCAT(style_value SEPARATOR ' ') style_values FROM style GROUP BY style_name
```

This will result in:

```
STYLE_NAME  STYLE_VALUES
body        background: #CCC; font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif; font-size: 40px; text-align: center;
h1          font-size: 50px;
h2          font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
```

Example fiddle:

### **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afca6/5)**

More information about GROUP_BY and GROUP_CONCAT: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

After that you can put all styles together in a simple manner:

```
foreach ($results as $css) {
    echo $css->style_name . " { " . $css->style_values + " }";
}
```

Comment: I was just about to post the for each loop to finish off ,but you beat me too it! I've chosen this answer for simplicity if using an MVC pattern, so the view would be a lot tidier.

Comment: Even more, it is much faster and results in cleaner code than using pure PHP for grouping the results.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still only just touching the of the true power of mysql

Answer (score 2):

Just use this :

```
$sql = 'SELECT style_name, style_value FROM style ORDER BY style_name';
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$map = array();

foreach ($results as $css) {
    $map[$css->style_name] .= $css->style_value;
}

foreach ($map as $style_name => $style_value) {
    echo $style_name . "{" . $style_value . "}" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use $unique_css[], you have each element (body, h1, h2 etc) in this array.

You can remove all brackets

```
str_replace("}", "", $unique_css[index]);
```

and add the end bracket

```
$unique_css[index] .= "}";
```

You can loop to add these actions in each index of the array

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at parsing the data first. Probably not the most efficient way of doing it but it may give you the most flexibility.

This is untested but you should get the general idea:

```
$uniqueStyles = array();

// Parsing the styles from the database.
foreach ($results as $cssRecord) {
    if (array_key_exists($cssRecord['style_name'], $uniqueStyles)) {
        $uniqueStyles[$cssRecord['style_name']][] = $cssRecord['style_value'];
    } else {
        $uniqueStyles[$cssRecord['style_name']] = array($cssRecord['style_value']);
    }
}

// To echo out the styles.
foreach ($uniqueStyles as $styleName => $styles) {
    echo $style . '{' . PHP_EOL;
    echo implode(PHP_EOL, $styles);
    echo '}' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First method

```
$sql = 'SELECT style_name, style_value FROM style ORDER BY style_name';
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$unique_css = array();

foreach ($results as $css) $unique_css[$css->style_name][] = $css->style_value;

foreach ($unique_css as $selector => $selector_styles) {
    echo $selector . ' {';
    foreach ($selector_styles as $style) {
        echo $style;
    }
    echo '}';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I’d group your results by tag name, and then implode the styles from there.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT style_id, style_name, style_value FROM style";
$res = $db->query($sql);

$styles = array();

while ($row = $res->fetchObject()) {
    $selector = $row->style_name;
    if (!isset($styles[$selector])) {
        $styles[$selector] = array();
    }
    $styles[$selector][] = $row->style_value;
}

foreach ($styles as $selector => $values) {
    echo sprintf('%s { %s }', $selector, implode('; ', $values));
}
```

Obviously this is just a crude implementation written off the cuff and shouldn’t be used verbatim, but should point you on the right path.